# How to center text under ASP. NET MVC3 Grid cell?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to center text in the cell here?

```
   grid.Column("TotalSum", "Total Sum", format: (item) => item.TotalSum.ToString("#,0.00"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found!

```
 grid.Column("TotalSum", "Total Sum", format: (item) => item.TotalSum.ToString("#,0.00"),style: "CenteredNumbers")
```

and add to CSS

```
.CenteredNumbers
{
    text-align:center;    
}
```